# What's the good Python syntax for ExecuteScript Nifi?

Tags: python, apache-nifi, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to consume streaming tweets with Nifi. After somes issues with `InvokeHTTP` processor, I choose to do my job with `ExecuteScript` processor and [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/).

I would like to get tweets in streaming and, one by one, give them to the rest of my Nifi process.

For that, I wrote the following script :

```py
from tweepy import Stream, API
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript

# All API keys / access token
consumer_key = "something"
consumer_secret_key = "something"
access_token = "something"
access_token_secret = "something"

# Initialize du proxy
proxies = {
    "http": "http_proxy",
    "https": "https_proxy"
}


# Listener class that contains all API functions for streaming tweets.
class Listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, nifi_session):
        super(Listener, self).__init__() # Overwrite constructor for declare flowfile NiFi
        self.nifi_session = nifi_session

    def on_data(self, status):
        # Convert string to json
        data = json.loads(status)

        # extract relevant information, for example, we use user's description only
        description = data['user']['description']

        # Give all this parameters at nifi
        session.putAttribute(self.nifi_session, 'data', description)
        session.transfer(self.nifi_session, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
        session.commit() # Commit to next nifi processor

    def on_error(self, status):
        if status == 420:
            return False


# Set flowfile NiFi
flowFile = session.get()

# Set OAuth with keys and tokens
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

listener = Listener()
twitterStream = Stream(api.auth, listener=listener, proxies=proxies)

# Try/catch for be sure that stream will be disconnect after error
try:
    twitterStream.filter(track=['nasa'])
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception !")
finally:
    print("...end")
    twitterStream.disconnect()

twitterStream.disconnect()
```

With this procedure, nothing happen on Nifi. However, I did test without `flowfile` and Nifi's `session` on other environment and that works. I suppose that the problem reside in my syntax to communicate with Nifi.

Edit : I can't use `GetTwitter` processor because it doesn't support proxy and I have to work with mine.

Thanks for help!

Comment: try to start scripting with smth simple. there are a bunch of issues in your code. for example no check `if (flowFile != None)`, no creation of new(out) file(s)... https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: I tried that quickly and that didn't work. I'll try it again but i'm not sure that is the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use the GetTwitter processor?

Comment: Because GetTwitter processor doesn't support proxies and I can't have a Internet connection without my proxy.